# Is it ok to crimp Romex to create a longer run

Tags: wiring

I know that I can join Romex in a junction box with wire nuts but can I crimp wire together with say SpliceLine Wire Connectors or some other device.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are lots of devices besides wire nuts you can use to splice Romex in a junction box, but generally splices *outside* of a box are prohibited.  The Spliceline push in connectors, insulated crimp connectors, any of them - has to be in a box.

There is a device made for Romex repair that is used to splice Romex outside of a box, but it's in a gray area, it's listing is for use in manufactured homes.  So it's OK for use in mobile homes, modular homes, etc., but not for built in place homes.  Some disagree with that, and use these devices in any kind of building.

Answer (score 2):

Not outside a junction box, no.  You have two options:

- Contrive a reason to have a junction box somewhere the wires can reach, and make the splice there.  Maybe you aim to wire your house with receptacle spacing that is *better than* the bare minimum called out by law.  Nuttin' wrong wit' dat!
- Carefully salvage the too-short cable(s) for use elsewhere, and replace the entire run with cable of adequate length. Done that before. You'll find uses for it.

If this is an old-work repair, there is a kit that is listed for splice repairs inside old work.  It's made by Tyco, and it's more expensive than the above choices but it'll get the job done.

Comment: Label the salvaged cables with their length. It could be months before you use any and you won't accurately remember, and it's obscenely inconvenient to keep unrolling and measuring. Voice of experience here.

Comment: @A.I.Breveleri yeah, I also learned that the hard way...

Comment: I will be butt splicing or crimping wires together in conduit where boxes are located. Wanted to make sure that the crimping method rather than the wire nut method would be ok "in a junction box"!
Thx for all the input as it was useful.